# MS Word autosequence bookmark only functioning on my PC, not other users'

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a simple code to autosequence a bookmark on a Word document that functions normally on my computer but the field is blank for other users. The document is stored on a shared drive so everyone has access to it.

Both the bookmark and the file where `PrivateProfileString` is storing the information are accessed in my environment when the macro runs. But not when a new document is created from the template on another's machine.

Here is the code

```
Sub AutoNew()
'
' AutoNew Macro
'
'
NCMR = System.PrivateProfileString("T:\_DOCUMENT CONTROL\All Current Documents\Text Files", _
"MacroSettings", "NCMR")
If NCMR = "" Then
    NCMR = 1
Else
    NCMR = NCMR + 1
End If

System.PrivateProfileString("T:\_DOCUMENT CONTROL\All Current Documents\Text Files", "MacroSettings", "NCMR") = NCMR

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("NCMR").Range.InsertBefore Format(NCMR, "20-00#")
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="\\T:\Quality\_NCMRs\" & Format(NCMR, "20-00#")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AutoNew` runs when a new document is created from a template. It is important to make sure that the template being distributed to others contains the macro code.

Often, especially when using the macro recorder, macros are created and saved by default in the `Normal.dotm` template, which is local to a user profile.

Always make sure the macros(s) is (are) copied to the file being distributed to others.

Note: In the code in the question it is also necessary to declare (`Dim`) the variable `NCMR` in the module or the macro to avoid compiler errors.